# creating auto resizeable views for different screen size in interface builder of xcode 8 using auto layout using multipliers

Tags: ios, swift, interface-builder, xcode8, ios-autolayout

I have tried to achieve this using `Autoresizing` in `IB`, using `constraints` such as

- pinning,
- aspect ratio,
- vertical spacing ,
- horizontal/vertical spacing,
- leading/trailing space;

but none seems to work uniformly for all screen sizes.

**For example**

the 4 image views in `iphone 7` is the required output positions for them but as soon as I check it in `iphone 7 plus` screen size or `iphone SE` screen size, these image views change position.

**below is the expected output as on iphone 7.**

**iphone7 Image**

[image]

**below is the *not expected* output as the positon of 4 image views change on iphone 7 plus.**
**iphone7plus**

[image]

**I want one more image to share of iPhone SE in which positon of the all 4 image views change more drastically, but not able to share cause reputation less than 10**

I will explain, for example, from 1st image i.e. of iphone 7, those 4 small image views can be taken as the expected position along with the image view with white background, but in other two screen sizes(iphone7 plus and iphoneSE) all views(4 small image view and the view with white back ground) should have **positioned** and **scaled** accordingly as compared to appearance on the first one.

**Update: code added**
I just made some changes to the one of the answer I got in this post by @diana_prodan, to get the expected output.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var imgOne: UIImageView!

@IBOutlet weak var imgTwo: UIImageView!

@IBOutlet weak var imgThree: UIImageView!

@IBOutlet weak var imgFour: UIImageView!

let icon_small : Float = 45.0
let icon_medium : Float = 50.0

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    let viewSize = UIScreen.main.bounds.size 
    print(viewSize)
    //image positioned
    //for 4' screen
    if (viewSize.height == 568.0){
        addImageAtPosition(imgOne, icon_small,41, 106 )
        addImageAtPosition(imgTwo, icon_small,105,91 )
        addImageAtPosition(imgThree, icon_small,105, 147)
        addImageAtPosition(imgFour, icon_small,139, 197 )
    //for 4.7' screen
    }else if(viewSize.height == 667.0){
        addImageAtPosition(imgOne, icon_medium,52, 135 )
        addImageAtPosition(imgTwo, icon_medium,127,106 )
        addImageAtPosition(imgThree, icon_medium,127, 172 )
        addImageAtPosition(imgFour, icon_medium,167, 230 )
     //for 5.5' screen   
    }else if(viewSize.height == 736.0){
        //add code woth cordinates for 5.5 screen size iPhone
    }
}
//method to positon image views
func addImageAtPosition(_ img:UIImageView, _ size: Float, _ y: Float, _ x: Float) {
    let imageView = img
    imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    self.view.addSubview(imageView)
    
    let imageSize: CGFloat = CGFloat(size)
    
    let topConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: imageView, attribute: .top, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self.topLayoutGuide, attribute: .bottom, multiplier: 1, constant: CGFloat(y))
    
    let leftContraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: imageView, attribute: .left, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: .left, multiplier: 1, constant: CGFloat(x))
    
    let widthConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: imageView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.width, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.equal, toItem: nil, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.notAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: imageSize)
    
    let heightConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: imageView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.height, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.equal, toItem: nil, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.notAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: imageSize)
    
    view.addConstraints([topConstraint, leftContraint, widthConstraint, heightConstraint])
}
```

}

**problem with this code is I have to get the coordinates for all image views view on different screen sizes and hardcode it, which is not a good practise I think**

Comment: Add your expected output.

Comment: @the_dahiya_boy : link has been given.

Comment: Pls add pic here as I have done, don't provide link bcz it decreases question  quality. Add your approach you have done so that we can check what wrong you have done.

Comment: @the_dahiya_boy I have done that now.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To acheive the expected output I went to this reference [reference]: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/AnatomyofaConstraint.html ,so all I had to is

- **select** one of the view and hold ctrl+ drag to the external view
- **then** hold shift and select *equal width* & *equal height*, *center
  horizontally in container* & *center vertically in container*.
- **then** selecting each constraints line(yellow coloured)or from *view controller scene column* and modify the multiplier until the yellow coloured line became blue i.e. until
  it satisfies the position where I have put my image views originally in view controller layout.

[here is the screen shot link it shows where to select constraints one by one(**on left**) and modify multiplier(**on right**).](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WqQN0.png)

Answer (score 2):

Take View A with give half height Constrain of main view's height. After that Give all images same height and width constarin. give one image's x,y constrain with view A's center. and link all images set defullts constrain.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set random values for top and left constraints of your ImageViews.

```
func addImageAtRadomPosition() {
    let imageView = UIImageView()
    imageView.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
    imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    self.view.addSubview(imageView)

    let imageSize: CGFloat = 50.0
    let screenHeight = UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height
    let screenWidth = UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width

    // Get random values which will be used for top and left constraints
    let randomYPosition = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(screenHeight - imageSize)))
    let randomXPosition = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(screenWidth - imageSize)))

    let topConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: imageView, attribute: .top, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self.topLayoutGuide, attribute: .bottom, multiplier: 1, constant: CGFloat(randomYPosition))
    let leftContraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: imageView, attribute: .left, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: .left, multiplier: 1, constant: CGFloat(randomXPosition))
    let widthConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: imageView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.width, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.equal, toItem: nil, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.notAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: imageSize)
    let heightConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: imageView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.height, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.equal, toItem: nil, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.notAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: imageSize)

    view.addConstraints([topConstraint, leftContraint, widthConstraint, heightConstraint])
}
```

Call this method as many times as your ImageViews count

```
for _ in 0...5 {
    addImageAtRadomPosition()
}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, I think I have asked the question wrong, I have edited it, thanks once again.

Answer (score 0):

If this is your expected output then notify me so that I can describe how to achieve this and if not then describe me what else you are expecting.

[image]

Comment below.

> edit

When I run the same VC in `iPhone 6+` I got below output. So consider this output.

[image]

Comment: thanks for reply, this is not the expected output.
I will explain, for example, from your 1st image i.e. of iphone 6s, those 4 small image views can be taken as the expected position along with the image view with white background, but in other two screen sizes(iphoneSE and iphone6S plus) all views(4 small image view and the view with white back ground) should have **positioned** and **scaled** accordingly as compared to appearance on the first one. @the_dahiya_boy

Comment: @Raj I didn't get your **positioned** & **scaled** point. Sorry.

Comment: thanks for reply once again, I have updated my post with code, also I will explain here.
The position and the size scaling of the four small image view in side the image view with white background should remain relatively constant for all screens.
And also the position with white background should be relatively constant with the super view for all screens.

Comment: @Raj First of all your constraints are not activated. So until they are not activated it does not work. Check edit my answer too.

Comment: #the_dahiya_boy I am using the same code to get the expected ouput:
[link] (https://i.stack.imgur.com/HePON.png)
[link] (https://i.stack.imgur.com/XsZU0.png)
[link] (https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZrL1R.png)

Comment: @Raj Then what is the problem? Did you check my edit answer.

Comment: problem is the code I have used to acheive the same, I have hardcoded the coordinates of image views for different screen, you can check the edited post of mine for code.
Also, can you move this discussion to chat, I am not able to cause of reputation points

Comment: You cannot join chat until you don't have 20 repo.

Comment: oh...okay.So, were you able to get my problem as described in my previous comment to you?I will repeat here again: **problem is the code I have hardcoded the coordinates of image views for different screen** , how to do it dynamically?

Comment: @Raj use constraints that will be better.

Comment: @Raj Till now you don't aware about constraints??

Comment: @ the_dahiya_boy I have used constraints, and every thing I can see on the Main.Storyboard IB of xcode 8.2.
The close I came in getting my expected output was when i applied **auto resizing** to views present on the viewcontroller and all of them were flexible across all screen sizes, but then I wanted to do it programmatically.

Comment: @Raj programatically you have to set frame. and even you can add constraints too. but it will work.